# python: extract float from a python list of string( AUD 31.99)

Tags: python, regex, excel, list, openpyxl

python: extract float from a python list of string( AUD 31.99).
I used openpyxl to read from an excel file the amount list. and i saved it in a list but the list is in string form like this:

```
['31.40 AUD', ' 32.99 AUD', '37.24 AUD']
```

I need to get the float from the string item list so that i can later save it in a new list to get the total of them.

Desired output:

```
[31.40, 32.99, 37.24]
```

I have already tried these:

```
newList = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", tot[0])
print(newList)
```

Output:

```
[31.40]
```

But How can I use this for all the item elements?

I am new to python, this is just for some work i do, wanted to see the total using python instead of using excel`s find & replace option.
thanks

Comment: Take a look here: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Comment: You should do the conversion before creating the list.

Comment: You are close.. but you are just passing tot[0].

Comment: try `[item.split()[0] for item in ['31.40 AUD', ' 32.99 AUD', '37.24 AUD']]`

Comment: Is it mandatory to use regex?

Comment: `re.findall` is good if you have the numbers in different contexts, not just the start of each item. You might also use `list(map(float, re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', " ".join(newList))))` if you follow the current approach.

Comment: Use the regex that languages use to parse numbers [(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)](https://regex101.com/r/8jAvQY/2). Cut out the middleman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) function:

```
inList = ['31.40 AUD', ' 32.99 AUD', '37.24 AUD']
output = list(map(lambda elem: float(elem.split()[0]), inList))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[31.4, 32.99, 37.24]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get list of values with regex, try

```
tot = ['31.40 AUD', ' 32.99 AUD', '37.24 AUD']
newList = [float(re.search('\d+\.\d+', fl).group(0)) for fl in tot]
print(newList)
# [31.40, 32.99, 37.24]
```

but using `split` seem to be easier solution in this case

```
tot = ['31.40 AUD', ' 32.99 AUD', '37.24 AUD']
newList = [float(item.split()[0]) for item in tot] 
print(newList)
# [31.40, 32.99, 37.24]
```

If second substring is always the same (`"AUD"`) you can also try

```
tot = ['31.40 AUD', ' 32.99 AUD', '37.24 AUD']
newList = [float(item.rstrip(' AUD')) for item in tot] 
print(newList)
# [31.40, 32.99, 37.24]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use a string split instead? I think it would be much simpler

```
ls1 = ['32.46 AUD', '17.34 AUD']

myFloats = []
for aString in ls1:
    aFloat = float(aString.split()[0])
    myFloats.append(aFloat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider handling errors. Here is one way for instance:

```
import re
import math

def float_from_string(str_):
    # Try to extract a floating number, if fail return nan
    r = re.search('\d+\.\d+', str_)
    return float(r.group()) if r else math.nan

tot = ['31.40 AUD', ' 32.99 AUD', '37.24 AUD', ' nonumberhere AUD']
totfloat = [float_from_string(i) for i in tot]

print(totfloat)
```

Returns:

```
[31.4, 32.99, 37.24, nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the list is as follows

```
l = ['31.40 AUD', ' 32.99 AUD', '37.24 AUD']
```

There are various ways to extract the floats. Will leave, below, five possible options.

---

**Option 1**

Using a regular expression with Python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) with a list comprehension as follows

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\d+\.\d+)')
l = [float(regex.search(x).group(1)) for x in l]

[Out]: 

[31.4, 32.99, 37.24]
```

---

**Option 2**

Using [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) as follows

```
l = [float(x.strip().split(' ')[0]) for x in l]

[Out]: 

[31.4, 32.99, 37.24]
```

---

**Option 3**

Using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) as follows

```
l = [float(x.split()[0]) for x in l]

[Out]: 

[31.4, 32.99, 37.24]
```

---

**Option 4**

One approach would be to remove the space and the currency (`AUD`) with use [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) as follows

```
l = [float(x.strip(' AUD')) for x in l]

[Out]: 

[31.4, 32.99, 37.24]
```

Assuming that one has a list with the various currencies (let's say `AUD`, `USD`, and `EUR`), as one's list only has `AUD`, one can use [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) as follows

```
hl = [' AUD', ' USD', ' EUR']

l = [float(x.strip(hl[0])) for x in l]

[Out]: 

[31.4, 32.99, 37.24]
```

---

**Option 5**

Another approach that works for this use case would be as follows

```
l = [float(x[:6]) for x in l]

[Out]: 

[31.4, 32.99, 37.24]
```

Note, however, that one might have to adjust the number or resort to a different method, depending on the floats in the strings on one's list.