# Extract float numbers from string in python

Tags: python

i want to extract the numbers from the **following string**:

FRESENIUS44.42 BAYER64.90 FRESENIUS MEDICAL CARE59.12 COVESTRO45.34 BASF63.19

I've tried the following approach but that didn't work:

```
l = []

for t in xs.split():

try:
    l.append(float(t))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

The **result** should be 44.42 64.90 59.12 45.34 63.19

Thank you!

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276828/2227895

Comment: @GermanLashevich Not a dupe (at least not of that question). The numbers in the OP are not separated from the non-numeric strings, so split will not work.

Comment: @DYZ The answer I linked is exactly what the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

list = ["FRESENIUS44.42", "BAYER64.90" "FRESENIUS MEDICAL CARE59.12", "COVESTRO45.34", "BASF63.19",]

newList = [float(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", i)[0]) for i in list]
print(newList)
```

First, we extract the floats using regex, then we convert into floats and append to list using list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working perfectly! Can i also use this Expression to filter the strings? => FRESENIUS BAYER ... ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
myStr = 'FRESENIUS44.42 BAYER64.90 FRESENIUS MEDICAL CARE59.12 COVESTRO45.34 BASF63.19'
outList = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", myStr)
    ['44.42', '64.90', '59.12', '45.34', '63.19']
finalStr = ' '.join(outList)
    '44.42 64.90 59.12 45.34 63.19'
```